# Custom hit test for a contextual menu

Tags: cocoa

I have a transparent NSView which draws a circle. I'd like to customize the hit testing used when displaying a contextual menu.

Currently it uses the bounding rectangle. I want to change it to test for a click inside the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding NSView menuForEvent: returning nil if you don't want the menu to show up and [super menuForEvent:] if you do.